# Issue Activating Jenkins File Leak Detector PlugIn

Tags: jenkins-plugins

We are having issues activating the Jenkins File Leak Detector PlugIn.  Error message is below.  Any thoughts?

Here's info that might be relevant:
RHEL 6.0
/tmp permissions:  drwxrwxrwt.  17 root    root    28672 Aug 31 08:42 tmp

[root@XXXX tmp]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_39"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_39-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)

```
Status Code: 500
Exception: java.lang.Error: Failed to activate file leak detector: Connecting to 0 2013-08-31 08:42:18 Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode): "Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400b7000 nid=0x380a runnable [0x0000000000000000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400b4800 nid=0x3809 runnable [0x0000000000000000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400b1800 nid=0x3808 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE "Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400af800 nid=0x3806 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE "Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40094000 nid=0x37b4 in Object.wait() [0x00007f3d3f17b000] java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor) at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) - waiting on <0x00000007c1eb1300> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock) at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118) - locked <0x00000007c1eb1300> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock) at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134) at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159) "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40092000 nid=0x37b3 in Object.wait() [0x00007f3d3f27c000] java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor) at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) - waiting on <0x00000007c1eb11d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock) at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485) at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116) - locked <0x00000007c1eb11d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock) "main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40006800 nid=0x37a8 runnable [0x00007f3d4802b000] java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.sendQuitTo(Native Method) at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:67) at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:46) at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:195) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.run(Main.java:50) at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.main(Main.java:35) "VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4008b800 nid=0x37ad runnable "GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40019800 nid=0x37a9 runnable "GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4001b800 nid=0x37aa runnable "GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4001d000 nid=0x37ab runnable "GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4001f000 nid=0x37ac runnable "VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400c9800 nid=0x380e waiting on condition JNI global references: 1129 Heap PSYoungGen total 55616K, used 2868K [0x00000007c1eb0000, 0x00000007c5cc0000, 0x0000000800000000) eden space 47680K, 6% used [0x00000007c1eb0000,0x00000007c217d398,0x00000007c4d40000) from space 7936K, 0% used [0x00000007c5500000,0x00000007c5500000,0x00000007c5cc0000) to space 7936K, 0% used [0x00000007c4d40000,0x00000007c4d40000,0x00000007c5500000) PSOldGen total 127104K, used 0K [0x0000000745c00000, 0x000000074d820000, 0x00000007c1eb0000) object space 127104K, 0% used [0x0000000745c00000,0x0000000745c00000,0x000000074d820000) PSPermGen total 21248K, used 4333K [0x0000000740a00000, 0x0000000741ec0000, 0x0000000745c00000) object space 21248K, 20% used [0x0000000740a00000,0x0000000740e3b460,0x0000000741ec0000) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.run(Main.java:50) at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.main(Main.java:35) Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:82) at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:46) at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:195) ... 6 more
Stacktrace:

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Error: Failed to activate file leak detector: Connecting to 0
2013-08-31 08:42:18
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode):

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400b7000 nid=0x380a runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400b4800 nid=0x3809 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400b1800 nid=0x3808 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400af800 nid=0x3806 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40094000 nid=0x37b4 in Object.wait() [0x00007f3d3f17b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007c1eb1300> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <0x00000007c1eb1300> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40092000 nid=0x37b3 in Object.wait() [0x00007f3d3f27c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007c1eb11d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
    - locked <0x00000007c1eb11d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40006800 nid=0x37a8 runnable [0x00007f3d4802b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.sendQuitTo(Native Method)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:67)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:46)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.run(Main.java:50)
    at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.main(Main.java:35)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4008b800 nid=0x37ad runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40019800 nid=0x37a9 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4001b800 nid=0x37aa runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4001d000 nid=0x37ab runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4001f000 nid=0x37ac runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400c9800 nid=0x380e waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 1129

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 55616K, used 2868K [0x00000007c1eb0000, 0x00000007c5cc0000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 47680K, 6% used [0x00000007c1eb0000,0x00000007c217d398,0x00000007c4d40000)
  from space 7936K, 0% used [0x00000007c5500000,0x00000007c5500000,0x00000007c5cc0000)
  to   space 7936K, 0% used [0x00000007c4d40000,0x00000007c4d40000,0x00000007c5500000)
 PSOldGen        total 127104K, used 0K [0x0000000745c00000, 0x000000074d820000, 0x00000007c1eb0000)
  object space 127104K, 0% used [0x0000000745c00000,0x0000000745c00000,0x000000074d820000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 4333K [0x0000000740a00000, 0x0000000741ec0000, 0x0000000745c00000)
  object space 21248K, 20% used [0x0000000740a00000,0x0000000740e3b460,0x0000000741ec0000)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.run(Main.java:50)
    at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:82)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:46)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:195)
    ... 6 more

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:725)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:776)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$12.dispatch(MetaClass.java:381)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:683)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:776)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:585)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:216)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
    at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:64)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:227)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Failed to activate file leak detector: Connecting to 0
2013-08-31 08:42:18
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode):

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400b7000 nid=0x380a runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400b4800 nid=0x3809 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400b1800 nid=0x3808 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400af800 nid=0x3806 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40094000 nid=0x37b4 in Object.wait() [0x00007f3d3f17b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007c1eb1300> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <0x00000007c1eb1300> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40092000 nid=0x37b3 in Object.wait() [0x00007f3d3f27c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007c1eb11d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
    - locked <0x00000007c1eb11d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40006800 nid=0x37a8 runnable [0x00007f3d4802b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.sendQuitTo(Native Method)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:67)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:46)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.run(Main.java:50)
    at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.main(Main.java:35)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4008b800 nid=0x37ad runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d40019800 nid=0x37a9 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4001b800 nid=0x37aa runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4001d000 nid=0x37ab runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d4001f000 nid=0x37ac runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f3d400c9800 nid=0x380e waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 1129

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 55616K, used 2868K [0x00000007c1eb0000, 0x00000007c5cc0000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 47680K, 6% used [0x00000007c1eb0000,0x00000007c217d398,0x00000007c4d40000)
  from space 7936K, 0% used [0x00000007c5500000,0x00000007c5500000,0x00000007c5cc0000)
  to   space 7936K, 0% used [0x00000007c4d40000,0x00000007c4d40000,0x00000007c5500000)
 PSOldGen        total 127104K, used 0K [0x0000000745c00000, 0x000000074d820000, 0x00000007c1eb0000)
  object space 127104K, 0% used [0x0000000745c00000,0x0000000745c00000,0x000000074d820000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 4333K [0x0000000740a00000, 0x0000000741ec0000, 0x0000000745c00000)
  object space 21248K, 20% used [0x0000000740a00000,0x0000000740e3b460,0x0000000741ec0000)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.run(Main.java:50)
    at org.kohsuke.file_leak_detector.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:82)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:46)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:195)
    ... 6 more

    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.file_leak_detector.FileHandleDump.doActivate(FileHandleDump.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:297)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:683)
    ... 55 more


Generated by Stapler at Sat Aug 31 08:42:23 EDT 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

The JVM reports an error during attaching to the other JVM

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
```

it seems attaching to a running process does not work. Either you have specified an invalid PID or the JVM that is running does not match to the one that you use to start file-leak-detector.

As a workaround you could try to inject the javaagent directly into the application instead of attaching to it. See http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/ for details.